# polars - Fill null over Groups

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I am trying to fill null timestamps over groups, my dataframe looks like this

|  | start | stop | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-12-08 06:40:53.734941+01:00 | 2022-05-16 10:16:18.717146+02:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-12-08 06:40:55.191598+01:00 | null | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-12-08 10:39:12.421402+01:00 | 2022-05-16 10:16:19.816922+02:00 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-12-08 10:39:12.634873+01:00 | 2022-05-16 10:16:19.817304+02:00 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-12-08 10:49:47.392815+01:00 | 2022-05-16 10:16:20.178050+02:00 | 5 |

The stop timestamps should be imputed from the next start.
My current implantation is:

```
   df = df.sort("start").with_columns(
       pl.col("start").fill_null(strategy="backward").over("group")
   )
   df = df.groupby("group").apply(
       lambda df: df.with_columns(
           pl.col("stop").fill_null(
               pl.col("start").shift(-1)
           )
       ),
       schema=None,
   )
```

This current implementation is slow. Is there a faster way to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your example code doesn't run. `schema` is raising an error. If I remove that your code fills the null with `10:16` which doesn't sound like what you want? It sounds like you want `10:39`? e.g. `df.with_columns(pl.col("stop").fill_null(pl.col("start").shift(-1)).over("group"))` (Although it ends up being `11:39` as the 2 columns have different timezones.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pl.coalesce()`.

Here is an example:

```
df.with_columns(
    stop = pl.coalesce(
        pl.col('stop'), pl.col('start').shift(-1).over('group')
    )
)

shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬──────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┬───────┐
│     ┆ start                            ┆ stop                             ┆ group │
│ --- ┆ ---                              ┆ ---                              ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str                              ┆ str                              ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪══════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 0   ┆ 2021-12-08 06:40:53.734941+01:00 ┆ 2022-05-16 10:16:18.717146+02:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 1   ┆ 2021-12-08 06:40:55.191598+01:00 ┆ 2021-12-08 10:39:12.634873+01:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 2   ┆ 2021-12-08 10:39:12.421402+01:00 ┆ 2022-05-16 10:16:19.816922+02:00 ┆ 2     │
│ 3   ┆ 2021-12-08 10:39:12.634873+01:00 ┆ 2022-05-16 10:16:19.817304+02:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 4   ┆ 2021-12-08 10:49:47.392815+01:00 ┆ 2022-05-16 10:16:20.178050+02:00 ┆ 5     │
└─────┴──────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴───────┘
```

In the example I used .over() so that it finds the next start within the same group.